# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto doesn't create tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jboss

I have some troubles and hope someone help me: hibernate doesnt create mysql sceme.
Here my config files:
**datasource-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd         
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <bean 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" 
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

         <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>


            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

                    </bean>
            </property> 
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="UsersBD" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

   <properties>
      <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>
   </properties>   
 </persistence-unit>
```

**applicationContext:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />

 </beans>
```

**Entity:**

```
package com.app.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="person")
@Table(name="PERSONS")
public class Person implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -4263067774169571725L;  

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String lastname;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personId")
private Collection<PersonsInf> infCollection;


public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public Collection<PersonsInf> getInfCollection() {
   return infCollection;
}

public void setInfCollection(Collection<PersonsInf> infCollection) {
    this.infCollection = infCollection;

}



}
```

So when i run my jboss server  and afer that look into mysql db  its empty..

Comment: can you show your debug statements ?

Comment: rather than defining your datasource properties values in beans.xml you can declare it in your persistence.xml. I dont see datasource id being called so probably it might not be setting up any connectivity with your database.

Comment: .here link to log file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uIKZTRJ1hHa1hJdzlyUWRyTTA/edit?usp=sharing
patiently waiting for your answer,thx

Comment: My target was config jpa without persistence xml, only with datasource-config.xml? or its impossible?

Comment: i even faced this issue but was not clear about the initialization of bean id "datasource" so placed all the database information in persistence.xml. And i have never used any datasource-config.xml for jpa(only persistence.xml). you can share the link where they use datasource-config.xml.